# Is the new edge browser debugger the same as the chrome browser debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, microsoft-edge, visual-studio-debugging

I'm following along in an online school, and they HIGHLY recommend chrome, but I don't understand why chrome still has the status when there is another browser that is built on the chrome platform that is just as good. (On the surface anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you comparing the developer tools in the MS Edge Chromium browser and Google Chrome browser?

If yes, the developer tools in the MS Edge Chromium browser offers similar features that you can find in the Google Chrome browser.

Both browsers use the same Chromium browser engine. So you can see the similar features in both browsers provided by the Chromium browser engine.

Here are some reference links that you can refer to get detailed information about the features provided by the MS Edge Chromium browser developer tools.

1. [Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium)
2. [What's New In DevTools (Microsoft Edge 83)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/whats-new/2020/03/devtools)

Let me know if I misunderstand something from your description. I will try to correct myself.

Comment: Delayed response, but yes. You under stood it write.